# Error exporting C# dll to TLB

Tags: c#, c++, com, typelib

I have a .NET DLL, which i export to TLB.
My dll relies on System.Drawing, IO and some other assemblies.

TlbExp seems to work fine, but it doesn`t export one of the types from Drawing assembly - Rectangle.
Verbose mode shows, that utility references to assembly, and it references all types but Rectangle. Types from other assemblies are fine.
So, when i do such thing in my sample C++ app:

```
#import "graph.tlb"
```

and build it, i get message, that type "Rectangle" is not referenced. Build produces tlh file, but there is no Rectangle despite the fact, that Rectangle has ComVisible(true) attribute. Don`t know what to do there.

Comment: Did you mean to add `typelib` tag instead of `tlb`?

Comment: It cannot be graph.dll, it should be graph.tlb.  Typo or real problem?  "type "Rectangle" is not referenced" is not the kind of error message the C++ compiler ever generates.  Yet another typo?  Rectangle is exposed in System.Drawing.tlb in the .NET framework directory.  Your graph.tlb should automatically include it.  Use the OleView.exe utility, File + View Typelib to have a look-see.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo.